# How to include HLS streams in Open Graph metadata for iOS Messages

Tags: ios, message, http-live-streaming, share-open-graph

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2444/_index.html) on link previews in Messages on iOS allows for image and video previews. I've gotten both to work, but the docs also suggest that HTTP Live Streams are supported:

> Video that can be streamed but not downloaded (such as HTTP Live Streams or QuickTime Reference Movies) will still play inline, but require the user to tap to start playback. Video that requires embedding HTML or plug-ins will not play inline.

However, I haven't been able to get it to work and I couldn't find anyone else who has. I've tried including the HLS stream (both master and the specific quality M3Us) in the `og:video` attribute, but Messages seems to give up trying to read it. Here's the HTML I'm working with:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="M3U link preview test">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SixDigitCode LinkPreviewTest">
<meta property="og:description" content="This is a test to see how Messages on iOS handles link previews">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sixdigitcode.github.io/LinkPreviewTest/video_img.jpg">
<meta property="og:video" content="https://sixdigitcode.github.io/LinkPreviewTest/m3ustream/002831_HD_COUNTDOWN_03.mov_28.m3u8">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1920">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="1080">
<meta property="twitter:player:stream" content="https://sixdigitcode.github.io/LinkPreviewTest/m3ustream/002831_HD_COUNTDOWN_03.mov_28.m3u8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you'd like to test out a live version I have one hosted [here](https://sixdigitcode.github.io/LinkPreviewTest/sample_m3u_test.html). Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!